# new windows computer, trying to sync my wallet from OSX

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I had a computer running OSX and a functional monero 12 GUI wallet operating with a little over 1.05 XMR, 2 weeks ago.. then I  had to sell my computer in order to cover the cost of an emergency veterinary visit. I was only able to afford a windows computer at walmart after paying the vet.. needless to say, I have been struggling to load my back up info from my OSX onto a new Windows pc.

I tried to dual boot ubuntu as my secondary OS booting with windows 10. Ubuntu seemed like it would be easy to use when I tried it for 10 minutes in Virtual Box, and many people use it for mining, so I tried it... two or three failed days of trying to load exe files on ubuntu with Wine crossover or other similar programs, and another 1 or 2 days trying to reinstall windows and removing the Grub bootloader. 
, 
I removed ubuntu, reinstalled a new copy of windows 10, and continued trying to get access to my wallet... I downloaded the 34GB Blockchain from getmonero.org- I used many commands inside the daemon after I finished downloading the blockchain, including these : ./monero-blockchain-import --verify 0 --input-file ./blockchain.raw
./monero-blockchain-import --guard-against-pwnage 0 --input-file ./blockchain.raw

i kept noticing it gets stuck, and had to restart many times.. I only have 4 GB RAM which I am hoping to upgrade today.

-----Since I began typing this question, I found this post on reddit - https://www.reddit.com/r/sumokoin/comments/8h2reo/solution_for_syncing_a_full_gui_wallet_faster_or/

I've already started it. I hope it's safe.

Comment: damn.. i just realized that was for sumokoin.. not xmr. Fu@%.